# How to get the zoom level of a mapview in Android when writing the test cases using solo in Robotium

Tags: android, robotium

I am  working on Robotium to perform an automation test an Android application.
in side the application a map view has to get the  zoom levels. Can any one explain how to get the zoom level of a map view by using Solo Object in Robotium tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
MapView map = (MapView)solo.getCurrentActivity().findViewById(your.package.name.R.id.google_maps);
int zoom = map.getZoomLevel();
```

I just tried this on my robotium testcase and it worked.  Also, you should try accepting answers, you'll get better/more responses!  Good luck